# Pytest webdriver fixture can't introspect some options

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

My framework currently only has one conftest.py file in it, which contains a fixture called browser which returns the webdriver object to the test.  We've recently tried to implement *metafunc.parametrize* in _generate_configuration_ in order to test cross browser and cross platform on browserstack, and have encountered a problem.  When the browser fixture is called at the beginning of a ui test, it doesn't know what current browser/os/version the test is running in based on the metafunc.parametrize method.

A nice example can be found here, but I like the idea of handling the webdriver object with a fixture because of how easy it is to handle the webdriver when it goes out of scope with the yield statement.  It also DRYs up the code: https://qxf2.com/blog/selenium-cross-browser-cross-platform-pytest/

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Webdrivers as fixtures are a great approach that I highly recommend, particularly because you get free teardown and driver.quit() once your tests have completed. If your driver is going to be dealing with different versions/browsers, I highly recommend you do the following:

1. Create a dictionary of run configurations that contain DesiredCapabilities for different browsers/versions
2. If you want to just test everything against all configurations every time, configure your parameterized test generation to iterate through all of the run configurations
3. If you want to be able to target specific ones, add a command line argument in your conftest.py for --run-configuration that maps to the desired DesiredCapabilities in your config.
4. Write a fixture called desired_capabilities (scope=session) that reads config.getoption('--run-configuration') and passes the associated DesiredCapabilities to the webdriver call in the driver fixture.